# jest mock function will not be called but console.log proves it is called

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs

I have the following function I would like to test:

```js
export const addLine = async (component) => {
  if (!component.cartExists) {
    await component.createMyCart(1);
  }
  console.log('updateMyCart',component.updateMyCart)
  return component.updateMyCart(2)
}
```

This is my test:

```js
it('channels added to cart line item', () => {
  const updateMyCart = jest.fn();
  const createMyCart = jest.fn();
  const component = { cartExists:false, updateMyCart, createMyCart };
  createMyCart.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(88))
  addLine(component);
  expect(createMyCart).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
  expect(updateMyCart)
    .toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
});
```

It shows the console.log in the function that is tested:

```
  ● Console

    console.log src/components/common/shared.js:155
      updateMyCart function mockConstructor() {
              return fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: 2

Number of calls: 0

  89 |     expect(createMyCart).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
  90 |     expect(updateMyCart)
> 91 |       .toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
     |        ^
  92 |     
  93 |   });
  94 |
```

The test will pass if I set `cartExist` to true and skip testing createMyCart was called:

```js
const component = { cartExists:true, updateMyCart, createMyCart };

createMyCart.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(88))
addLine(component);
// expect(createMyCart).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
expect(updateMyCart)
  .toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
```

It also passes when I remove the `await` in `await component.createMyCart(1);` but `cartExists` is false

Comment: Did you try `await addLine(component)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that was it. Feel dumb not realizing it is async

Answer (score 1):

As in comment, I missed waiting for `addLine` to finish: `await addLine(component)` and `it('channels added to cart line item', async () => {` solved it